# OpenCL Windows AMD Error - opencl an invalid option was specified

Tags: windows, opencl, amd-gpu, ati

I was trying to build a very simple kernel that compiles on Ubuntu. However, on Windows it gives me a very strange error:

Upon catching and printing the build error as such:

```cpp
catch (cl::BuildError e)
{
    auto buildInfo = e.getBuildLog();
    for (auto &pair : buildInfo)
        std::cerr << "Device: " << pair.first.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl <<
                                   pair.second << std::endl;
    error("Error",
          __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, __FILE__);
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
Device: Pitcairn
An invalid option was specified
Error
```

Why is this happening? What does this error even mean? I have an ATI Radeon R7 370 and Windows 10.

Comment: What are the build options passed to clBuildProgram? Looks like one of the flags passed is invalid.

Comment: There were no build options passed, just the default ones. Only the program src and context were passed

Comment: Without more information is difficult to know what the problem is. Can you paste the output of clinfo (OpenCL version and platform)? If you are trying to build an OpenCL 2.0 program on an OpenCL 1.2 platform you may end up with an error like that one.